# How to put a number in a space if it exists, but a space otherwise?

Tags: java, formatting

How do you print to a line, `"  1"` if it a one, but `" 10"` if it's a ten, or `"100"` or it's on hundred?

Essentially, there are three character spaces no matter what, but is a number if the number is big enough; otherwise, it is a space.

Comment: could you bring us a graph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the `printf()` ([docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)) method.

Example:

```
System.out.printf("%1d%n", 1);
System.out.printf("%2d%n", 1);
System.out.printf("%3d%n", 1);
```

Output:

```
1
 1
  1
```

If you want to print leading zeros, you can do:

```
System.out.printf("%03d%n", 1);
```

Output:

```
001
```

Comment: I'd like to mention that you should use %n instead of \n, as the former is platform-independent.